# List of file extensions for supported MPMoviePlayerController media types

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, file-type

Playing media in the MPMoviePlayerController is a fallback option in my app - generally use a UIWebView.  I need a list of typical file extensions for types of media supported by the MPMoviePlayerController - anybody have that?

I do not need a list of supported media types - I need a list of likely file extensions for those types.

**Edit**
Further clarifying in response to the answer by sch, the Apple documentation merely mentions the following file extensions:

.mov
.mp4
.mpv
.3gp

I would be curious to know, at minimum, if the following can be played by iOS (and therefore is support by MPMoviePlayerController), or any others I may be overlooking:

- mp3 (I know this one is supported)
- wav
- aif
- aiff
- mid
- midi
- m4p
- mpa
- au
- wma
- ram
- rm
- ogg